# how to make parent to do same animation as child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a football skill animation animating the character and the character is the child
when the animation ends, the character child returns back the position where started

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4uaP.png)

i want the parent to also perform the same animation as that of child, so that it does not go back to the starting point

Comment: -> [Root Motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html)

Comment: Ah I see your problem here is the animation itself , you see you need to use animations that play on fixed location and the translations part you make it with code so in your animation exporting settings you need to make the position (x,y,z) fixed and the movement you make it with script

Answer (score 0):

You should update the [`AnimationClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimationClip.html) import settings.

Select Bake into Pose for **Root Transform Position (XZ)**. And then *Orignal* from the dropdown. [Check this link for detailed info.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimationClip.html#ClipProperties)